# Taking string as an input with array of structures

Tags: arrays, c, input, data-structures, structure

In this code and this line - `scanf("%s %d",a[i].name,&a[i].roll);` - if I try to give `&a[i].name`, I get a warning:

> format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’

even though argument 2 has type `char (*)[10]`.  Why is it so? For getting input the object should precede with the `&` operator, right?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct student{
        char name[10];
        int roll;
    };
    
int main(){

    struct student a[4];
    
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
        **scanf("%s %d",a[i].name,&a[i].roll);**
       
    }
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%s\n",a[i].name);
    }
     
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell that code works (minus the `**` that I assume you added for marking the line). Perhaps you fixed something a you copied it into the question?

Comment: Yes the code works but my doubt is "scanf("%s %d",a[i].name,&a[i].roll); " when i try to add &a[i].name it shows format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’ why is it so